# Angular2 Karma/Protractor - wait for element to become enabled

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-runner

In my Angular2 application I have a Karma unit test which needs to wait for an element to become enabled.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to make the test wait for this element to become enabled before trying to click on it.

```
  it('should check the fundDropdown exists', function () {

        browser.get(url);

        var menuStratItem = element(by.xpath('/html/body/alg-app/mainviewer/p-tabview/div/ul/li[2]/a'));

        // Need to wait for this element to become enabled before I try to click it...
        expect(menuStratItem.isEnabled()).toBe(true);

        menuStratItem.click();

        expect(element(by.id('fundDropdown')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
  });
```

How can I wait for this element to become enabled before continuing with the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I had to use a .then call to execute code in when the condition became true. The full answer looks like this...

```
  var url = 'http://uat.viewer3.web.algebris.lan';
  var ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions
  var timeout = 60000;

  it('should check the fundDropdown exists', function () {

        browser.get(url);

        var menuStratItem = element(by.xpath('/html/body/alg-app/mainviewer/p-tabview/div/ul/li[2]/a'));

        browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(menuStratItem), timeout).then(function () {
              expect(menuStratItem.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
              menuStratItem.click();
              expect(element(by.id('fundDropdown')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Ben Cameron.It worked for me.

**Its always better to use isDisplayed() instead of isPresent()**.

```
 it('should check the fundDropdown exists', function () {

    browser.get(url);

    var menuStratItem = element(by.xpath('/html/body/alg-app/mainviewer/p-tabview/div/ul/li[2]/a'));

    browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(menuStratItem), 10000).then(function () {
          expect(menuStratItem.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
          menuStratItem.click();

       expect(element(by.id('fundDropdown')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should use `browser.wait()` instead of what you are currently doing. Something like this should work:

```
var ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions
var timeout = 60000;

it('should check the fundDropdown exists', function () {
    browser.get(url);

    var menuStratItem = element(by.xpath('/html/body/alg-app/mainviewer/p-tabview/div/ul/li[2]/a'));

    //use browser.wait to wait for element to be clickable
    browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(menuStratItem), timeout);
    menuStratItem.click();

    expect(element(by.id('fundDropdown')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have looked into it and found that the .wait isn't a blocking function. You need to handle the promise using a .then. Thanks for the hint though.